# Which chess GUIs support the chess variants Atomic and King of the Hill?

Tags: chess-variants, stockfish, atomic-chess, king-of-the-hill

I want to play against Stockfish offline because I'm going on a trip. I downloaded the compiled exe from [GitHub](https://github.com/ddugovic/Stockfish) since my laptop will have limited Internet connection. After loading it into the Arena GUI I noticed it only supports Chess960. Which GUIs support the chess variants Atomic and King of the Hill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three chess variant GUIs supporting both atomic and king of the hill that I am aware of:

- [PyChess](https://pychess.github.io/download)
- [WinBoard/XBoard](http://hgm.nubati.net)
- [Cutechess](https://github.com/cutechess/cutechess)

The latter is well suited for automated engine matches and human vs. engine games, but less for game analysis. All three should work fine with the multi-variant Stockfish you downloaded.

Comment: Thank you. Im using PyChess, I would use Winboard/Xboard but I dont know how to set it up

Comment: Is the problem with installing Winboard itself or with running Stockfish in it? The most recent Winboard you can get at http://hgm.nubati.net/WinBoard-AA.zip, but running Stockfish in it requires the UCI2WB adapter, which should be included already. Alternatively you can also try my other Stockfish variant fork https://github.com/ianfab/Fairy-Stockfish which does not need an adapter, see https://github.com/ianfab/Fairy-Stockfish/wiki/Usage#xboardwinboard, but it does not support atomic.

Comment: The problem is in setting up  Stockfish because I don't understand what to do after launching the program itself. Thank you for telling  me about UCI2WB